# Is the HOUR in the Calendar class based on a specific time zone?

Tags: java, calendar, gregorian-calendar

I'm a little confused.  I've been working with the Calendar and GregorianCalendar classes in Java and I have been printing the hour, but it says 4, and it is 11 where I am now.

My question is, is the hour based on the local time? Is it based on a specific time zone?

I've looked around, but I haven't found a clear answer.

```
    Calendar today = new GregorianCalendar();
    int y = today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int h = today.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int ap = today.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
    System.out.println(y + " " + h + " " + ap);
```

And my output:

```
2013 4 1
```

Comment: Show some code related to how you are printing.

Comment: Edited to show code and output.

Comment: What are you using as IDE?... When I run this I get local time (I'm using netbeans)...

Comment: I'm thinking that might be the issue now.  I am actually compiling on Ideaone.com because I don't have an IDE on this computer.

Comment: When you create a `Calendar` it is based on their time, not yours.

Comment: Yeah, I'm guessing the site is hosted somewhere in London or another place in that time zone.  My mistake.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The no-arg constructor of GregorianCalender uses `Timzone.getDefault()` as its timezone. This is the timezone (or in other words: the local time) of the JVM executing your code. All of the calendar fields, including `Calendar.HOUR`, are based on this timezone.

If this differs from your local time, then either the JVM is in a different timezone or the JVM (or rather its hosting computer) is configured incorrectly.